# DateItem SmarthGwt

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Hi I use a DateItem in my project, everything works fine but the problem is that when I display the month it shows me [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUNxn.png)
it displays the same characters in  June and July

I want to indicate the language of the application is French

how can I show 4 characters in the DateItem, like this [janv,févr,..., juin, juil,...]

this is my source code

```
    public DateItem monthFilterDate = new DateItem();
    monthFilterDate.setTitle(TAMessages.getMessage("ta.date.month"));
    monthFilterDate.setShowTitle(false);
    monthFilterDate.setAttribute("selectorFormat", 
    DateItemSelectorFormat.MONTH_YEAR);
    monthFilterDate.setWidth(20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that you have found a SmartGWT bug.

Probably their translations have not properly been tested.

You may want to report that: https://forums.smartclient.com/